# Make Header dissapear when full screen mode is detected in browser (F11)

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

For this type of question i think there is no need to show you my code, but in case there is a need to do so i will show my code.

**Here is my question**

Is there any way to make it so a part of my page disappears or hide it when the browser (IT, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, etc) is set to Full Screen ( Pressing F11)

I have set up an internal website where i show dashboards and they are displayed on big screens.

All i want is the page to  detect if the browser is in full screen, if so i want to header (includes logo + Navigation Menu) to hide and reappear when the browser is exited from full screen mode.

**EDIT: here is some sample code of the picture displayed below**

```css
/*---------------- Default styles---------------- */

* {

  margin: auto;

  outline: 0;

  padding: 0;

  border: 0;

  text-decoration: none;

  vertical-align: baseline;

}

html {

  font-size: 75%;

}

body {

  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;

  font-size: 1rem;

  background-color: #f7f7f7;

  width: 100%;

  overflow-y: scroll;

}

/*----------------Header Styles----------------*/

header {

  width: 80%;

  text-align: center;

}

header img {

  padding-top: 3%;

  padding-bottom: 3%;

}

/*------------------SUB MENU STYLE-----------------*/

#wrapper {

  width: 100%;

  margin: 20% auto;

  text-align: left;

}

#nav ul {

  background-color: #ffd800;

  list-style-type: none;

  padding: 0;

  margin: 0;

}

#nav ul li {

  display: inline-block;

}

#nav ul li:hover {

  background-color: #6FC4D5;

  /*Borders*/

  border-radius: 5%;

  -moz-border-radius: 5%;

  -webkit-border-radius: 5%;

  border: 0px solid #000;

}

#nav ul li a,

visited {

  display: block;

  padding: 15px;

  color: #000;

  font-weight: bold;

  text-decoration: none;

}

#nav ul li:hover > ul {

  display: block;

}

#nav ul ul {

  display: none;

  position: absolute;

  background-color: #e8e4e4;

  min-width: fill-available;

}

#nav ul ul li {

  display: block;

}

#nav ul ul li:hover {

  background-color: #6FC4D5;

}

#nav ul li:hover ul li a,

visited {

  color: Black;

  font-weight: 500;

}

#nav ul ul li:hover > ul {

  display: block;

}

#nav ul ul ul {

  margin-top: -21%;

  width: 100%;

  margin-left: 100%;

  background-color: #e8e4e4;

}

/* Dropdown Menu Arrow */

#nav ul li > a:after {

  color: #000;

  font-style: normal;

  content: '▾';

}

#nav ul li > a:hover:after {

  color: #444;

  content: '▸';

}

#nav ul li > a:only-child:after {

  content: ' ';

}

#nav ul li ul li > a:after {

  color: #000;

  font-style: normal;

  content: '▸';

}

#nav ul li ul li > a:hover:after {

  color: #444;

  content: '▾';

}

#nav ul li ul li > a:only-child:after {

  content: ' ';

}

/*----------------Article Style----------------*/

article {

  width: 80%;

  margin-top: 0%;

  margin-bottom: 5%;

  text-align: center;

}

#hr h1 {

  padding-top: 0%;

  padding-bottom: 0;

}

article h1 {

  margin-top: 5%;

  font-size: 2em;

  text-align: center;

}

article p {

  width: auto;

  text-align: left;

  font-size: 100%;

  margin: 3% 0%;

  padding: 0% 10% 0% 10%;

}

article p img {

  margin: 1% 5%;

  padding-left: 19.5%;

  padding-right: 19.5%;

  width: 50%;

}

/*----------------PDF File view----------------*/

object {

  padding-top: 5%;

  width: 60%;

  height: 1070px;

}

#pdfsideview embed {

  padding-top: 5%;

  width: 65%;

  height: 730px;

}

iframe {

  width: 100%;

  height: 1070px;

}

caption {

  padding: 5% 0% 5% 0%;

  font-size: 2rem;

  font-weight: bold;

}

table {

  width: 70%;

  border-collapse: collapse;

  border-spacing: 0;

}

#dialing table {

  width: 100%;

}

table,

th,

td {

  border-collapse: collapse;

  border-spacing: 0;

}

th {

  height: auto;

  text-align: left;

}

th,

th:hover {

  background-color: #f7f7f7;

}

td {

  text-align: left;

  height: auto;

}

tr:hover {

  background-color: #6FC4D5;

  /*Borders*/

  border-radius: 3%;

  -moz-border-radius: 3%;

  -webkit-border-radius: 3%;

  border: 0% solid #000;

  width: auto;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" name="keywords" content="HTML, CSS, XML, XHTML, JavaScript" http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <script src="../scripts/modernizr-1.5.js"></script>

</head>

<body>


  <header style="width:100%; background-image: url(../../images/Header-Pic.png); background-position: right;background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: 100% 100%">


    <a href="../index.html">
      <img src="../../images/wiki.png" alt="">
    </a>

  </header>
  <div id="navWrapper">
    <div id="nav">
      <ul>
        <!--HOME DROPDOWN MENU-->
        <li><a href="../index.html">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>

          <!--DIRECTORY MENU-->
          <a href="#">Directory</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="../subpages/EmailHierarchy.php"> Email Hierarchy</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="../subpages/DialingCodes.html">Dialing Codes</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="../subpages/PhoneDirectory.php">Phone Directory</a>
            </li>

          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>

          <!--TIPS and HINTS MENU-->
          <a href="#">Tips and Hints</a>
          <ul>
            <!-- Arrage this sub menu in alphabetical order!!-->
            <li><a href="../subpages/TipsAndHints.html">Tips and Hints</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="../subpages/WindowsShortCuts.php">Windows Keyboard Shortcuts</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <!--HR DROPDOWN MENU-->
          <a href="#">HR</a>
          <ul>
            <!-- Arrage this sub menu in alphabetical order!!-->
            <!--<li><a href="../subpages/HR.html">HR</a></li>-->
            <li><a href="../subpages/DressCodePolicy.html">Dress Code Policy</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="../subpages/GymMembershipReimbursementProgram.html">Gym Reimbursement Program</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="../subpages/HolidaySchedule.html">Holiday Schedule</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="../subpages/PTOPolicy.html">Time Off Policy</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <!--TUTORIALS DROP DOWN MENU-->
          <a href="#">TURORIALS</a>
          <ul>
            <!-- Arrage this sub menu in alphabetical order!!-->
            <li><a href="../subpages/HowTo.html" style="font-weight: 400">About this PAGE</a> 
            </li>
            <li><a href="../subpages/CleanCookies.php">Clean Cookies and Cache</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="../subpages/GoogleDrive.php">Google Drive</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="../subpages/LogMeIn.html">Find Computer Name</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="../subpages/SetUpNetworkPrinter.php">Set up Network Printer</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="../subpages/VPN.php">VPN</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>

          <!--DIRECTORY MENU-->
          <a href="#">Dashboards</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="../Dashboards/Call Calls Week Compare.php" target="_blank">Call Center Calls Week Compare</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="../Dashboards/Call Center Dashboard.php" target="_blank">Call Center Dashboard</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="../Dashboards/Pet Plus Dashboard.php" target="_blank">Dashboard</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="../Dashboards/Sales Dashboard.php" target="_blank">Sales Dashboard</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <article>
    <div id="dialing">
      <table class="sortable">
        <caption style="padding-top: 50px;">Dialing Codes</caption>
        <tr>
          <th>Feature</td>
            <th>Code</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>All: Call Flow Toggle
          </td>
          <td>*28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>All: Time Condition Override
          </td>
          <td>*27</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Asterisk General Call Pickup
          </td>
          <td>*8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Call Forward All Activate
          </td>
          <td>*72</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Call Forward All Deactivate
          </td>
          <td>*73</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Call Forward All Prompting Activate
          </td>
          <td>*720</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Call Forward All Prompting Deactivate
          </td>
          <td>*74</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Call Forward Busy Activate
          </td>
          <td>*90</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Call Forward Busy Deactivate
          </td>
          <td>*91</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Call Forward Busy Prompting Activate
          </td>
          <td>*900</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Call Forward Busy Prompting Deactivate
          </td>
          <td>*92</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Call Forward No Answer/Unavailable Activate
          </td>
          <td>*52</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Call Forward No Answer/Unavailable Deactivate
          </td>
          <td>*53</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Call Forward No Answer/Unavailable Prompting Activate
          </td>
          <td>*520</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Call Forward Toggle</td>
          <td>*740</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Call Waiting - Activate
          </td>
          <td>*70</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Call Waiting - Deactivate
          </td>
          <td>*71</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Camp-On Cancel</td>
          <td>*83</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Camp-On Request</td>
          <td>*82</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Camp-On Toggle</td>
          <td>*84</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>ChanSpy</td>
          <td>555</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Check Recording</td>
          <td>*99</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Dial Voicemail</td>
          <td>*98</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Direct Dial Prefix</td>
          <td>*</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>DND Activate</td>
          <td>*78</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>DND Deactivate</td>
          <td>*79</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>DND Toggle</td>
          <td>*76</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Email completed dictation
          </td>
          <td>*35</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Findme Follow Toggle</td>
          <td>*21</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>In-Call Asterisk Attended Transfer
          </td>
          <td>*2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>In-Call Asterisk Toggle Call Recording
          </td>
          <td>##</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Intercom prefix</td>
          <td>*80</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>My Voicemail</td>
          <td>*97</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Park Prefix</td>
          <td>*86</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Perform dictation</td>
          <td>*34</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Phonebook dial-by-name directory
          </td>
          <td>411</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Pickup ParkedCall Prefix
          </td>
          <td>*85</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Queue Callers</td>
          <td>*47</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Save Recording</td>
          <td>*77</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Set user speed dial</td>
          <td>*75</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Speeddial prefix</td>
          <td>*0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>User Intercom Allow</td>
          <td>*54</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>User Intercom Disallow</td>
          <td>*55</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>ZapBarge</td>
          <td>888</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </article>

</body>

</html>
```

Below is an example of my webpage. 
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Using the Fullscreen API in web browsers

> The user could, for instance, exit fullscreen, something that might be
>   good for you to know. For that we have a `fullscreenchange` event, that
>   you can apply both to the element that requested fullscreen, but also
>   to the document. Then we just detect the fullscreen state and take act
>   accordingly, like this:

```
document.addEventListener("fullscreenchange", function () {
    fullscreenState.innerHTML = (document.fullscreen)? "" : "not ";
}, false);

document.addEventListener("mozfullscreenchange", function () {
    fullscreenState.innerHTML = (document.mozFullScreen)? "" : "not ";
}, false);

document.addEventListener("webkitfullscreenchange", function () {
    fullscreenState.innerHTML = (document.webkitIsFullScreen)? "" : "not ";
}, false);

document.addEventListener("msfullscreenchange", function () {
    fullscreenState.innerHTML = (document.msFullscreenElement)? "" : "not ";
}, false);
```

SRC: http://robertnyman.com/2012/03/08/using-the-fullscreen-api-in-web-browsers/

Answer (score 4):

If only you hadn't mentioned Opera in your question, you could have achieved this with pure CSS, without needing any JavaScript, by using the [`:fullscreen`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:fullscreen) pseudo class. Unfortunately, though Opera doesn't yet support it and IE only introduced it in v11. Check the full support table at [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=fullscreen).

Here's how you'd do it:

```
header:-moz-full-screen{
    display:none;
}
header:-moz-fullscreen{
    display:none;
}
header:-ms-fullscreen{
    display:none;
}
header:-webkit-full-screen{
    display:none;
}
header:-webkit-fullscreen{
    display:none;
}
header:fullscreen{
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: For some reason it doesn't seem to be working for me. I added to code to my CSS file but when i press F11 in chome IE, Firefox.. the header doesn't "disappear". Is there anything else that i may have to do in order for this to work? When i press F11 would like only the table which is an Iframe to be visible.

Comment: Apologies, I forgot to hyphenate the `-moz-` and `-webkit-` versions in my answer, I've fixed that now.