# Detect if in fullscreen modus (3d flipbook)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, pdf

I use the 3d flipbook jQuery plugin (http://codecanyon.net/item/real-3d-flipbook-jquery-plugin/4281720).

I have styled the flipbook a little bit myself with these values:

```
 .flipbook-main-wrapper{
    left:350px;
    right:350px;
    background: #4c4c4a !important;
    top:180px;
    bottom:200px;
    z-index:99999;
}
```

But when you click the fullscreen mode I want to give it a class with these values:

```
.flipbook-main-wrapper.active{
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
```

I already tried a click event on that fullscreen button, I also tried several fullscreen detections I found on stackoverflow but none of them are working. Is there another way to detect if the flipbook is opened in fullscreen modus?

Thanks!

Comment: The answers to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29998173/ may be of use to you.

Comment: Thanks! I found my answer in that question!

Comment: Which one? Mine or Pedro's?

Comment: Beware of poor browser support with that. I've just updated by answer over there to include a link to the relevant table on caniuse.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Shaggy I found my answer:

```
.flipbook-main-wrapper:-moz-fullscreen{
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
.flipbook-main-wrapper:-ms-fullscreen{
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
.flipbook-main-wrapper:-webkit-fullscreen{
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
.flipbook-main-wrapper:fullscreen{
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
```

So simple!